# Email attachment to user on form submission

Tags: solspace-freeform, email, attachment

I have created a form using Freeform Lite add-on and would like to send/email a PDF guide to user  submitted the form. Is there a way we can do it without having file type field into the form?

Comment: Couldn't you use the field and just hide it using `type="hidden"` or just `style="display: none"` ?

Comment: @jrothafer but how can we put file to be attached with email.

Comment: It would help if you could provide some basic information about the EE system you are working on - for example giving the version number of EE and of Freeform Lite you are using.  Thanks!